# NetBeans hangs as soon as i open any xml file

Tags: xml, netbeans, jboss, struts2

I m currently working on struts 2 with netbeans ide. whenever i open any xml file, the netbeans hangs out. i googled but unable to find any solution. please help me to get rid of this issue.
futher running any web application on the netbeans (even very very small application) is taking too much time( 1.30 mins to 2.30 mins). please suggest me what to do to solve this problem (i m using jboss as sever).
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Netbeans normally works very well with XML files. I guess that your XML problem must be because of an installation error. I would reinstall the application.

In order to reduce the web application startup time, keep just the necessary applications in your JBoss path. You may have many projects around, that do not need to be parsed and deployed each time, and they do.